# a problem in understanding an inequality

Tags: integration

I tried a lot to understand why the inequality that has epsilon/4 is correct

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsKqo.jpg]

but I couldn't prove it .can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Is this by Milnor?

Comment: Yes, this is Milnor's article.